# Where to Publish a mobile application Iphone/Android/Something else?

Tags: iphone, android, app-store, google-play, mobile-application

If I want to publish a mobile application? Where should I publish one from profitability point of view. IPhone, Android, or something else? And what are the reasons for this?

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the top few percentile of paid apps (iOS App store or Android marketplace) are reported to sell well.

So the main reason developers publish apps these days are:

1. Having really strong marketing communication channels outside the app stores.
2. Very poor business planning (regarding the actual market statistics).
3. Gambling instinct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first of all it is a good question, many programmes come across this, If you want to make android applications, publish them on the android marketplace, i think it only costs like 25 american dollars per month or per year, i forgot, to publish an application on the marketplace, now if you want to program cocoa, the language apple uses, then make some mobile applications for the itunes store, im not sure how much it costs or even how to do it but it shouldnt be too hard, If all you want is profit, then i would go with the android marketplace, its cheap and i dont know if you know this or not but on average per day 500,000 new people are added to the android marketplace, there are tuns of people out there who love cheap fun apps, if you charge 1$ per app and 10 people buy your app per day, thats 300$ per month just for that app, it depends what kind of app it is too, more people buy games than applications, so if you really want some cash from android, i would make a really fun game thats pretty cheap and youll have people from all over playing your app. Good luck! Hope this helped!

Comment: The android market fee is actually a one-time $25 registration fee.

Comment: I think you've a good point. The first part of the your answer was for me understood. But the other part about you prefer android was the one I wanted. Thank you! Let me know if you've other thoughts.

Comment: I think that android is a rapidly growing market and there's a lot of opportunities for programmers who are creative and i think its your best option, i mean even I'm willing to pay a dollar or 2 to play a game i hear is good. If your good with the basics of java then it shouldn't be too hard for you to create an app that will grab people's attention and get you some money.

Comment: Money?  Currently, the median iOS paid app seems to be averaging somewhere around 1 sale per day, and the median Android paid app is selling about 5X less, according to word on the street.

Comment: umm well if you look at games like angry birds? you cant tell me hundreds of people dont but that game everyday, on average they might not do so well but the big ones do very well and all you need is a good idea to make a big app like that. Angry birds is a very simple game, i could have made it.

Comment: Actually, I've very good experience in mobile applications. I already developed apps/games for others. What I want is what strategy I should take to get more money, and which market I should go for.

Comment: Ok well thats good, i think the best thing for you would be develop an android application, specifically a game. More people buy games than apps. I think its your best option.